BorrowMutError for following implementation in runtime
Im using a DFS algorithm in which i need to mutate parent element , but getting BorrowMutError at runtime
I need the exact implementation where i need to pass the parent in dfs function and need to mutate it accordingly.

use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}
#[allow(dead_code)]
impl TreeNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        TreeNode {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
}
pub fn distribute_coins(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> i32 {
    fn dfs(current: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> i32 {
        match current {
            Some(node_) => {
                let node = node_.borrow();
                let left_moves = dfs(node.left.clone(), Some(Rc::clone(&node_)));
                let right_moves = dfs(node.right.clone(), Some(node_.clone()));
                let moves = left_moves + right_moves;
                let x = node.val - 1;

                if let Some(ref parent) = parent {
                    parent.clone().borrow_mut().val += x
                }
                moves + x.abs()
            }
            None => 0,
        }
    }
    dfs(root, None)
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};
    use super::{distribute_coins, TreeNode};
    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let mut example = Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(0)));
        example.borrow_mut().left = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(3))));
        example.borrow_mut().right = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode::new(3))));
        assert!(distribute_coins(Some(example)) == 3);
    }
}



Rc<RefCell> is one of the worst possible representations for a graph. The best is, of course, to use a library.

You have to release the borrow of node_ while you operate on its children because it will be a parent at some point and thus be mutably borrowed as well. You can reacquire the immutable borrow on node_ after you work on its children. (I cannot speak to the correctness of the algorithm in  general; once the panic is fixed, the test still fails.) You should change the Some branch to the following:
Some(node_) => {
    let node = node_.borrow();
    // get left and right ahead of time so we can un-borrow node_
    let left = node.left.clone();
    let right = node.right.clone();

    // end borrow
    drop(node);

    // node_ can now be borrowed mutably
    let left_moves = dfs(left, Some(Rc::clone(&node_)));
    let right_moves = dfs(right, Some(node_.clone()));
    let moves = left_moves + right_moves;

    // reacquire borrow on node_ to get x
    let node = node_.borrow();
    let x = node.val - 1;

    if let Some(ref parent) = parent {
        parent.clone().borrow_mut().val += x
    }
    moves + x.abs()
}

